# Optimum Size of Message in weblogic

Tags: configuration, jms, weblogic-10.x

In my production server I was getting the below exception

weblogic.socket.MaxMessageSizeExceededException: Incoming message of size: '10000080' bytes exceeds the configured maximum of: '10000000' bytes for protocol: 't3'.

To resolve this I increased the value of -Dweblogic.MaxMessageSize.

My question is what should be the optimum size of this flag? I just can not keep on increasing
it to resolve this issue in future. Is there another flag which will help me set this flag
to a particular value and also the application runs without any issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no global optimum size.  They probably have 10000000 as the default because they assume that'll be most peoples max.  Realistically it will be limited to whatever your producer is sending as a max.  Is there a limit for the producer in what they can send?

In general, you want to avoid large objects.  but you can't always.

Comment: I agree. But the second part of my question is, if there is another flag which can keep this value under check and if we can use both to help keep the objects not very large.

Comment: No, I am only aware of this parameter (and the fact that the sender was able to bypass it makes me think the sender has a higher value).  You can do lots of things to avoid large messages.  Don't use stream/byte/object messages, as those tend to be very large.  If you can, put a reference to a file, and have the consumer pull a file by this reference.